# Interpolating between two arrays with changing values

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I don't know if there is a name for this kind of problem or not, much less a solution, so all I can do is try to describe it the best I can.

Suppose I have an array in the following state:

**[0, 0, 3, 0]**

Later the values in the array have changed to:

**[5, 0, 0, 0]**

Let's call the old state **A** and the new state **C**. We want to find a state **B** that represents an intermediate form between the two.

What I actually want for the intermediate form is **[0, 4, 0, 0]**, such that the state change through all three phases represents the motion of something that is changing position and value.

Simply averaging the two states does not work, as that would produce the following intermediate form: **[2.5, 0, 1.5, 0]**, a wildly wrong representation of what I'm after.

Another example:

**A: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6]**

**C: [0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 0]**

**the intermediate form should be:**

**B: [0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0]**

Part of the problem is I'm having trouble defining the problem. It's clear what result I want given the inputs, but I can't seem to describe the result in terms of the inputs using precise enough language.

**What is the correct way to describe the result in terms of the inputs so that I can phrase the problem better?**

And, ultimately, is there an algorithm that can produce what I'm after?

Answer (score 0):

This works on your two test cases.

```
def avg(l1, l2, base=0):
    ans = []
    L = len(l1)
    i = 0
    while i < L:

        e1 = l1[i]
        e2 = l2[i]

        if e1 != base or e2 != base:
            left = i
            if e1 != base:
                first = l1
                second = l2
            else:
                first = l2
                second = l1

            while i < L and second[i] == base:
                i += 1

            ans += [base] * (i - left + 1)
            avg_idx = (left + i) // 2
            avg_val = (first[left] + second[i]) / 2
            ans[avg_idx] = avg_val

        else:
            ans.append(base)


        i += 1

    return ans

print(avg([0, 0, 3, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0])) # [0, 4.0, 0, 0]
print(avg([0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6], [0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 0])) # [0, 3.0, 0, 0, 7.0, 0]
print(avg([2,2,3,2], [5,2,2,2], base=2) # [2, 4.0, 2, 2]
```

Comment: This works when the unchanged values are all 0 as in my examples, but I don't think this will work when they are something else. e.g. [2,2,3,2] and [5,2,2,2] should produce [2,4,2,2]... I' wonder if that can be solved by changing `if e1 != 0 or e2 != 0` to just `if e1 != e2`? Trying this out in my language of choice now...

Comment: See my updated answer. In general I see no way to identify the "base" without specifying it. After all, [2,2,3,2] and [5,2,2,2] could be an array where 2 becomes 5 at index 0, 2 becomes 2 at index 1, etc.

Comment: I see. I guess there is inherent ambiguity then. I suppose I could pre-calculate a 'base' by checking for the most common value between the two inputs. Of course this wouldn't work in the case where there are no common values, e.g. [1,2,3] and [5,6,7] ==> [3,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have "clear situation" (possible vectors states), I'll assume that if two elements in input vectors are greater then zero, it can be only in two cases:

a) i == j
b) i == j + 2 (or generally: (i+j)%2 = 0

i: index of element in v1
j: index of element in v2

In that case, this pseudo code may give a desired result:

```
vector v1, v2;
vector v3 = [0];  --all zeros in resultant vector 
pos1 = pos2 = -1; --position of elements in vectors
for (i = 0; i < size(v1); i++)
    {
    if (v1(i) > 0)
       pos1 = i;     
    if (v2(i) > 0)
       pos2 = i;
    if (pos1 >= 0 && pos2 >= 0)
       {
       pos3 = pos1 + pos2;
       if ((pos3 % 2) != 0)   
          {
          --how to handle this?
          --error? 
          } 
       pos3 = pos3/2;
       v3(pos3) = (v1(pos1) + v2(pos2) )/ 2;                   
       pos1 = pos2 = -1;
       }
    }
```

v3 is resultant vector, i.e. one with "interpolated" values.
It should work for cases you've presented...I hope so :)